# The probability of rolling $N$ 10-sided dice and forming groups that add at least 10

Tags: probability, dice

I'm trying to answer this question for an RPG game. The player (or the GM) has to roll $N$ 10-sided dice and then she has to form groups that sum at least 10 (I'll call them Raises, using the game term).

As an example, if I roll 3d10 and get 10, 7 and 3, I get two Raises: {10}, {7,3}. If I roll 3d10 and get 2, 9 and 9, I get only one Raise: {2,9}.

I'm interested in computing the probability of getting $R$ Raises by rolling $N$ d10, either in a closed form or recursively (I'm thinking of putting this in a script to compute the expected value for some fixed values of $N$).

I'm trying to use [this entry on Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html) to solve the problem, but I'm still stuck.

Any help will be appreciated. This is by no means an assignment or a homework or a life-saving problem. I'm doing it just out of curiosity. Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: to clarify, the player should choose the largest number of Raises. For example, if I roll four dice and get 4, 5, 6, 10, although {4, 5, 6, 10} is one Raise, {4, 6} and {10} (or {5, 6} and {10}) are two Raises. In this case the player should choose the second alternative.

Comment: Why would {2, 9} be considered a Raise? Don't the elements in a Raise set have to sum to 10 exactly?

Comment: Dammit! I'll edit it right away: I meant to say "that sum at least 10". Thank you!

Comment: Do I roll all $N$ dice at once, or do I roll them one at a time and have to use their results in order?  For example say I roll 6, 3, 9, 8, 5, 2.  If I can use the dice in the order I please, I can make three raises: $6 + 5 = 11, 3 + 8 = 11, 9 + 2 = 11$.  But if I have to use the dice "in order" then I get a raise from $\{ 6, 3, 9 \}$ and another from $\{ 8, 5\}$, so I only get two.

Comment: You roll them all at once and then you choose how to form the Raises. To clarify (and I'll add it to the question) the number of Raises should be the largest one.

An example: if I roll 4, 5, 6 10, then {5, 10, 4, 6} is a Raise, but {10}, {4, 6} (or {10}, {5, 6}) are two Raises and a leftover die. In this case the player should prefer the second alternative to the first.

Comment: There is  a propability $p(N,s)$ that the sum of the faces after $N$ rolls is $s$, where
$$
p(N,s)=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10} p(N-1,s-i);\quad p(0,s)=\delta_{0,s}.
$$
One can use $R\le \lfloor s/10\rfloor$ as an upper limit of the number of raises, assuming that
the faces are fortunately balanced, so the probability
of getting $R$ raises is approximately supported by $s$ is in the range $10R\le s\le 10R+9$,
which means the probability is approximately $\sum_{s=10R}^{10R+9} p(N,s)$. The full answer
is obviously much more complicated.